# FIbonacci sequence in ARM assembly

Tags: recursion, assembly, arm, fibonacci

Just started learning assembly on the ARM processors(cortex M4) and I'm trying to play a bit with recursion, using the stack etc.
I'm trying to implement a code which will load the first 5 FIbonacci numbers in the register R3.
I managed to write some code using recursion in assembly for example sum of first n numbers or factorial of a number and I could do that but in the case of fibonacci we have to remember both fibonacci(n-1) and fibonacci(n-2) at each iteration and that I was not able to do.

This would be a C function I'm trying to implement in assembly:

```
int fibbonacci(int n) {
   if(n == 0){
      return 0;
   } else if(n == 1) {
      return 1;
   } else {
      return (fibbonacci(n-1) + fibbonacci(n-2));
   }
}
```

This is the code I wrote:

```
__main
        MOV     R0, #4
Sum     
        CMP     R0, #1
        BEQ     done
        SUBS    R0, R0, #1
        BL      Sum
        POP     {R1, R2}
        ADD     R0, R1, R2
        MOV     R3, R0
        PUSH    {R0, R1}
        BX      LR
        
Stop    B       Stop
        
        
done
        MOV     R0, #0
        MOV     R3, R0
        PUSH    {R0}
        
        MOV     R0, #1
        MOV     R3, R0
        PUSH    {R0}
        
        BX      LR
        ALIGN
```

What my logic was is that we recursive all the way to when R0 is equal to 1 and then we go into the 'done' subroutine where we load R0 with two values(0 and 1) and push these values on the stack. Then we use the register R3 to see the values and then we return to what would be fibonacci(2) on this line:

```
POP     {R0, R1}
```

So here we extract those two values from the top of the stack(1 and 0) and do calculate fibonacci(2)=fibonacci(1)+fibonacci(0) and store it in R0 and then R3.
Then we store R0(1) and R2(1).
The program kinda works as in it displays all the numbers in the sequence in the register R3 however I was not able to make the program stop after 4 numbers. For example since in the above example I have R0=4 in the beginning of the program I want the code to show me the first 4 numbers in the sequence then go to the endless while loop(Stop B Stop). I was not able to do this I guess I have to make use of the LR somehow and push it on the stack and pop it but I'm not sure where I could do this so the program returns after displaying only 4 numbers.

Please help me fix this. Thank you!

Comment: Push whatever registers you need to save the first thing you do when you enter the function, pop them the last thing you do before you return from the function.

Comment: See https://godbolt.org/z/54aW9M1T9

Comment: Your code to a `bl` before any pushes, so it's losing its own return address, and not saving any state for recursion.  It also (almost) never makes sense for `push` to be the last thing you do before `bx lr`.  The caller owned the stack space above the incoming SP (unless there are stack args), and you should return with SP pointing where it was before.  So if the last thing you do is push, that can only make sense if you already popped some of your caller's stack frame (stack args).  But you have no stack args, and definitely no reason to be popping random parts of your caller's stack frame.

Comment: Your C code is also flawed. Both input and output should be unsigned int.

Comment: Ok...I will keep trying to work on the code...it is very difficult for me to realise how to save both previous versions on each iterations...Like for every Fibonacci(n) I have to somehow get from the stack the Fibonacci(n-2) and Fibonacci(n-1). If it was only 1 I could but getting the last two previous results confuses me a lot :(

Comment: Don't get caught up by the fact that it's recursive.  When you're translating the C to asm, calling yourself is no different from calling any other function, unless you optimize away the recursion and just use a loop.  Anything you need to read *after* a function call has to be in a call-preserved register, or memory.  You have to avoid stepping on any memory or registers you don't own.  Look `clang -O1` output https://godbolt.org/z/oocETffKh.  (unlike Michael's link which used `-O2` so clang turned one of the recursive calls into a loop.)